# Angularjs dynamically set attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, attributes, setattribute

I'm trying to dynamically add attribute to div in controller in angular js.

```
 var table = document.getElementById("div_id").setAttribute("ng-click", "function_name()");
 $scope.$apply();
```

Everything looks fine, in the debugger i see that attribute was added but it doesn't execute my function. Do you have any ideas how to add attributes to the existing div and how to make it works?

Comment: I think you shouldn't call that function say just `function_name`.

Comment: Can't you add an condition in your click function with a boolean value, which is false by default and then set it true where you want to "add" this function?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to recompile your div

```
var el = angular.element("div_id");
$scope = el.scope();
$injector = el.injector();
$injector.invoke(function($compile){
   $compile(el)($scope)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r2vb1ahy/

Comment: This will work only in debug build. In production build where you have this $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false), $scope will not be available like this.

Comment: Thank you! You're a saviour!

Answer (score 17):

get element by id and set new attribute and value

```
 var el =angular.element('#divId');
 el.attr('attr-name', 'attr-value');
```

Comment: isn't this DOM manipulation? ie, what you're not supposed to be doing with Angular?

Comment: No, DOM manipulation IS what you are supposed to do when needed. The only requirement is to keep DOM manipulation outside of the controller, and keep it in custom directives.

Answer (score 0):

To Set attribute dynamically use

```
var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#divID'));
myEl.attr('myattr',"attr val");
```

To get attribute value use

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector('#divID'));
alert(myEl.attr('myattr'));
```

To remove attribute use

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
myEl.removeAttr('myattr');
```

Comment: totally different topic than the op's question

Answer (score -1):

Angular2 is providing `[attr.<attribute name>]` to bind attribute values.

```
<div id="divID" [attr.role]="roleVal">
  This text color can be changed
</div>
```

In component class:

```
  addAttr() {
    this.roleVal = 'admin';
  }

  removeAttr() {
    this.roleVal = '';
  }

  checkAttr() {
    alert(this.roleVal);
  }
```

From http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/02/set-attribute-and-remove-attribute-with.html

Comment: he said: "dynamically add attribute to div in controller in angular js". Not angular2 and not in html.